# How to use UNC path for WMI event monitoring

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to use WMI to monitor a folder for changes using a vbs script, but it will be a network drive. There are a several users that will be executing this script and it is possible that the mapped drive letter will be different for some. Therefore, I want to use the UNC which won't change.

I've tried changing strDrive and strFolder to every combination of the UNC and folder. The script executes, but doesn't recognize any of the events unless I use the drive letter.

```
' VBScript source code
'WMIFileEvents.vbs
intInterval = "2"
strDrive = "f:" 'or \\mypath\
strFolder = "\\vbs\\"
strComputer = "." 


Set objWMIService = GetObject( "winmgmts:" & _ 
    "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _ 
    strComputer & "\root\cimv2" )
strQuery =  _
    "Select * From __InstanceOperationEvent" _
    & " Within " & intInterval _
    & " Where Targetinstance Isa 'CIM_DataFile'" _
    & " And TargetInstance.Drive='" & strDrive & "'" _
    & " And TargetInstance.Path='" & strFolder & "'"
Set colEvents = objWMIService. ExecNotificationQuery (strQuery) 
WScript.Echo "Monitoring events...[Ctl-C] to end"

Do 

    Set objEvent = colEvents.NextEvent()
    Set objTargetInst = objEvent.TargetInstance

    Select Case objEvent.Path_.Class 
        Case "__InstanceCreationEvent" 
            WScript.Echo "Created: " & objTargetInst.Name 
        Case "__InstanceDeletionEvent" 
            WScript.Echo "Deleted: " & objTargetInst.Name 
        Case "__InstanceModificationEvent" 
            WScript.Echo "Modified: " & objTargetInst.Name
    End Select 
Loop
```

I'd be happy to either modify this script to work with the UNC or to return the drive letter from the UNC (I can't figure out how to do that either). I'm willing to go outside of VBS to either VBA or the shell if that makes it easier to solve.

Comment: You can't use UNC paths, this is certain. See [CIM_DataFile class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/cim-datafile) *(Only instances of files on local fixed disks will be returned.*) Other than that, even if this script works the way you want, do you realize that only the changes made by the computer running this script can be monitored (hint: `strComputer = "."`), is this the behavior you expect?

Comment: This actually is the behavior that I expect (although I didn't realize that since I'm no VBS expert). Long story short, I've got no choice but to execute a process from Excel VBA and then monitor a folder for information on what happened. This Excel Workbook and a copy of the VBS script will be exist on each computer that has to use the tool.

Comment: I ended up "solving" the issue by using CreateObject("WScript.Network") to get a list of all attached network drives for a given user, finding an open slot and manually attaching the desired UNC. It's clunky, but so is the entire project.

Comment: Nice. You can add your solution as an answer and accept your own question BTW.

Comment: Thanks. I had to fix my loop and got distracted with other items for a few days. It's up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution. I found out that the Wscript.Network object has the EnumNetworkDrives property which is a list of all currently used drive letters. Then I just cycle through the alphabet to discover which letter is currently not in use and map the UNC to it manually. Even if they already have the drive attached, I just map and remove at the end.

This assumes that the users are not every possible drive letter which is safe in my case. An alternative would be to map the drive letter back to a UNC identify if a currently used drive has my needed path.

I hope there is a better way to see if an item is in a list than my clunky looping and I'm open to suggestions, but it works for me and didn't take long to write.

```
'Establish all letters of the English Alphabet (assuming these can all become drive mappings)
Set driveLetters = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

driveletters.add "A:"
driveletters.add "B:"
driveletters.add "C:"
driveletters.add "D:"
driveletters.add "E:"
driveletters.add "F:"
driveletters.add "G:"
driveletters.add "H:"
driveletters.add "I:"
driveletters.add "J:"
driveletters.add "K:"
driveletters.add "L:"
driveletters.add "M:"
driveletters.add "N:"
driveletters.add "O:"
driveletters.add "P:"
driveletters.add "Q:"
driveletters.add "R:"
driveletters.add "S:"
driveletters.add "T:"
driveletters.add "U:"
driveletters.add "V:"
driveletters.add "W:"
driveletters.add "X:"
driveletters.add "Y:"
driveletters.add "Z:"


'Find the first available open drive mapping

Set oWSN = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set oDrives = oWSN.EnumNetworkDrives

For i = 0 to driveletters.Count - 1 step 1
    in_list = False
    For j = 0 to oDrives.Count - 1 Step 2
        If oDrives.Item(j) = driveletters.Item(i) Then
            in_list = True
        End If
    Next

    If in_list = False Then
        strDrive = driveletters.Item(i)
        Exit For
    End If
Next

oWSN.MapNetworkDrive strDrive, "\\unc\path"

'Monitoring code

oWSN.RemoveNetworkDrive strDrive, True
```